# Multiple Chrome shortcut apps from the same domain?

Tags: outlook.com, google-chrome

In Chrome (for Mac), you can turn any website into a standalone web application (a.k.a. Site Specific Browser) by going to the site, clicking the three stacked dots in the upper-right of the window, and then selecting *Create Shortcut* from the *More Tools* menu:

[image: create shortcut]

This is super handy for making a standalone web mail client or web calendar… which is exactly what I'm trying to do. I've made a shortcut app of Outlook Mail from this URL:

`https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox`

Now, when I try to make a separate shortcut app for the Outlook calendar at this URL:

`https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/workweek`

The original Outlook mail shortcut app just gets rewritten to become the Outlook calendar. I'm assuming this is because they're both coming from the same domain and subdomain.

Is there a way around this? Is it possible to have two seperate shortcut apps coming from the same domain?

Comment: I have the same problem but only on one pc. On the other it just somehow works.